# Disable Watson Assistant Environment not working for live and draft env

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I have created a Watson Assistant service and created a simple action bot. My aim is to control the amount of user that can access the service monthly. Checking on the [API Docs](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant-v2#getenvironment) I found out that is possible to update my environment to disable my action skill and block users to use the bot. However I am facing some issues regarding API use.

I have created a version and deploy it on my live environment. I tried to update my draft and live environment with this API:

```
/v2/assistants/{assistant_id}/environments/{environment_id}
```

```json
{
    "skill_references": [{
        "skill_id": "my skill id",
        "type": "action",
        "disabled": true,
        "snapshot": "2",
        "skill_reference": "actions skill"
    }]
}
```

I am getting the following response:

```json
{
    "error": "Data Exception: Skill References can not be deleted. The cardinality of the skill_references (1) is less than expected: (2)",
    "code": 400
}
```

Do you guys know if I can disabled my live or draft environment or have any idea on how to make the service unavailable after hit the maximum amount of user?

Comment: Have you updated the included skill_references or left out one when updating the environment?

Comment: data_henrik I have two environment, one live and other as draft, I tried to update just the live one.

Answer (score 1):

The entire body of `skill_references` needs to be supplied on an Update environment call.

You can get the full array of `skill_references` by first performing a [GET `/v2/assistants/{{assistant_id}}/environments/{{environment_id}}`](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant-v2#getenvironment), and then changing the `disabled` state on the `action` skill reference.

Based on your error, I think what you're missing from the Update request is the `skill_reference` for your search skill, which is created by default for every environment.

Comment: It worked partially, when I supplied the entire body of `skill_references` the API returned 200, however the skill was not disabled. I mean, I tried to disabled the entire live environment and although the API returned 200 I still able to chat with my assistant.